# Flex spark component implementation error

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

Hi I am having this error when I try to paste in code of a spark component. The component is a DataGrid and it needs to be a spark and not a mx.

The Spark Component:

```
    <s:DataGrid includeIn="admin" x="150" y="288" requestedRowCount="4">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="dataField1" headerText="Column 1"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="dataField2" headerText="Column 2"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="dataField3" headerText="Column 3"></s:GridColumn>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
    <s:typicalItem>
        <fx:Object dataField1="Sample Data" dataField2="Sample Data" dataField3="Sample Data"></fx:Object>
    </s:typicalItem>
    <s:ArrayList>
        <fx:Object dataField1="data1" dataField2="data1" dataField3="data1"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object dataField1="data2" dataField2="data2" dataField3="data2"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object dataField1="data3" dataField2="data3" dataField3="data3"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object dataField1="data4" dataField2="data4" dataField3="data4"></fx:Object>
    </s:ArrayList>
</s:DataGrid>
```

The Error:

```
Could not resolve <s:DataGrid> to a component implementation.
```

How can I resolve this error. I need to make my DataGrid into a Spark Component. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Spark DataGrid was introduced in Flex 4.5 .  This error means two things:

1. You are using an old version of the SDK, in which the Spark DataGrid does not exist.
2. You are using the correct version of the SDK, but for some reason deleted, or changed the name of the 's' namespace import; thereby leading the compiler to not be able to find any components in the 's' namespace.

If you post the line for your top level component, we could eliminate option 2 easily.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
      minWidth="800" minHeight="600" currentState="login" width="1020"
      creationComplete="DatabaseService.send()">

Comment: Yes, that's right I did somehow manage to change the code and saved the project. The SDK is installed and the DataGrid was originally a Spark component before the software changed my DataGrid to a mx.

Comment: This line 'xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"' means that you are properly importing the spark nameSpace; so I'd assume you're just using an early version of the Flex SDK (4.0 or 4.1).

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project -> Properties -> Flex Compiler -> Use a specific sdk = 4.6(or whatever Higher SDK you have).